# get the value of a xml tag

Tags: c#, xml

In below xml, I want to fetch the value of tag ID where name tag have 
 value 'HighLevelReport%'.

```
<RunResults xmlns="http://www.hp.com/PC/REST/API">
  <RunResult>
    <ID>17245</ID>
    <Name>output.mdb.zip</Name>
    <Type>Output Log</Type>
    <RunID>4196</RunID>
  </RunResult>
  <RunResult>
    <ID>17246</ID>
    <Name>VuserLog.zip</Name>
    <Type>Output Log</Type>
    <RunID>4196</RunID>
  </RunResult>                            
  <RunResult>
    <ID>17248</ID>
    <Name>Reports.zip</Name>
    <Type>HTML Report</Type>
    <RunID>4196</RunID>
  </RunResult>
  <RunResult>
    <ID>17249</ID>
    <Name>HighLevelReport_4196.xls</Name>
    <Type>Rich Report</Type>
    <RunID>4196</RunID>
  </RunResult>                          
</RunResults>
```

currently I am using dataset to get the value

```
using (DataSet reader = ds.ReadXml(xml))
{                               
    DataRow[] DR = reader.Tables[0].Select("Name like '%HighLevelReport%'");
    int testID = Convert.ToInt32(DR[0].ItemArray[0].ToString());
}
```

Please help me with some other option of doing same.

Comment: What is your question and what is the problem you facing?

Comment: Seems like the prime use case of [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using a `DataSet` for this rather than an XML API like LINQ to XML? That would make the querying really simple.

Comment: I found it easier to do it in  DataSet. However, I really not in favor of it. If someone helps me with other approach. like @JonSkeet mentioned LINQ to XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid using a `DataSet` unless you really, really need to. If you're just dealing with XML, use an XML API. I find LINQ to XML the best for this. For example:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.hp.com/PC/REST/API";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var ids = doc.Root
             .Elements(ns + "RunResult")
             .Where(rr => ((string) rr.Element(ns + "Name"))?.StartsWith("HighLevelReport") ?? false)
             .Select(rr => (string) rr.Element(ns + "RunID"));
```

Here's a complete example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Alternatively, use XDocument.Load to load from a file
        string xml = File.ReadAllText("test.xml");
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        XNamespace ns = "http://www.hp.com/PC/REST/API";
        var ids = doc.Root
            .Elements(ns + "RunResult")
            .Where(rr => ((string) rr.Element(ns + "Name"))?.StartsWith("HighLevelReport") ?? false)
            .Select(rr => (string) rr.Element(ns + "RunID"));
        foreach (var id in ids)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(id);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Where` clause here handles the `Name` element being missing - the cast to `string` would return null, and so `StartsWith` wouldn't be called. If the `RunID` element is missing, you'll end up with a null element in your output.